# FIPS_mode_set failed: fingerprint does not match

Tags: ios, objective-c, good-dynamics

Does anybode use Good Dynamics latest version (2.0.447) or any other with FIPS enabled?
Application runs on sim but crashes on device. Here's the log:

[image]

p.s. it seems that I've done all necessary things such as adding these lines to xcconfig files

FIPS_PACKAGE=$(CURRENT_ARCH).sdk

LDPLUSPLUS=/Good Technology/Good.platform/FIPS_module/$FIPS_PACKAGE/bin/gd_fipsld
LD=/Good Technology/Good.platform/FIPS_module/$FIPS_PACKAGE/bin/gd_fipsld

and also a couple of strings in target settings as recommended by the GD guide.

Comment: Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this also.  It turns out the default.xcconfig file that was present was not properly set up in the project settings (Project/Info/Configurations).  The guidance I should have checked against is here:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/BasingBuildConfigurationsonConfigurationFiles.html

Comment: Unfortunately, not my case.

Answer (score 0):

Please check once Good SDK installation location in your mac with your default.xcconfig file in your xcode. This may be also cause the issue.

In `default.xcconfig`, replace the paths with the following code :

```
LDPLUSPLUS=/Good Technology/Good.platform/FIPS_module/$FIPS_PACKAGE/bin/gd_fipsld 
LDUTILDIR=/Good\ Technology/Good.platform/FIPS_module/$(CURRENT_ARCH).sdk/bin
```